# Laravel scheduled job did not resume after maintance mode

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I did a maintanace on my laravel app by **php artisan down**. Then again after 15 minutes I did **php artisan up**.

But the scheduled jobs have not still resumed. They are not being executed as it was before.

Schedueled jobs are not being executed even when I manually give the command. ex: php artisan my:command

Comment: try to make logs of your cronjob.

Comment: If they are not running when you do `php artisan my:command` then it's more likely that the maintenance broke something and the fact that they are scheduled tasks is not really what's relevant here. Can you share any error logs from when you attempt to run `php artisan my:command` ?

Comment: No error to be seen. just that the task itself is not being fired

Comment: No scheduled commands are ready to run. found in log file

Comment: does the `storage_path('/framework/down')` file exist? It should only be there when down for maintenance.

Comment: @Dilani can you please show me your code

Comment: Doing php artisan view:clear solved the issue. Still, I do not understand how and why

Answer (score 0):

I think by making logs of your cronjobs will help you.

## First Method

remove this part from you cronjob

```php
>> /dev/null
```

Now add log file path in you cronjob

```php
* * * * * php /var/www/html/project/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/project/mylog.log 2>&1
```

create a log file and this file 777 (writable) permission.

so you can check what actually happening

## Second Method

Or you can use method appendOutputTo() in your kernal.php

```php
$schedule->command('inspire')->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo($filePath);
```

$filePath is a path of a log file you can give a public path or storage path